# React Navigation nested drawer menus

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm creating a React Native application using React Navigation for navigation, as well as Redux. I currently have a drawer navigator containing multiple items (such as "Home", "Favorites", "Categories", and "Manufacturers"). Currently all of these just take you to another screen.

However I am trying to make Categories and Manufacturers open up a "sub drawer" or "sub menu", either clearing the current items in the drawer or just opening a fresh drawer, and then showing more specific items (such as "Coupes", "Sedans", and "SUVs" for Categories, and "Audi", "BMW", and "Volkswagen" for Manufacturers, to name a few) along with a back button to return to the previous drawer menu. How do I do something like this?

I'm still new to React Native/Navigation/Redux and I've been searching around for about a week for examples on how to do something like this, but only found one example on freeCodeCamp, which is very similar to what I want but doesn't seem to play well with Redux.

-Edit-

Here's a link to a basic snack:
https://snack.expo.io/SJ37V32zr

Comment: Hi there! Please provide relevant samples of your code so we have some concrete material to help you (especially the part where you are defining your drawers).

Comment: @Remeus Okay, I added a link to a snack since I figured a short code block wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: Did you figure out how to go about nesting ? @Kmango